# MySQL boolean type to return boolean query?

Tags: mysqli, boolean

I'm trying to see if its possible to test for a certain result specific to a boolean value in an SQL database.

```
if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `work_orders` WHERE `is_open` = '1' ")) 
{
    show_workorder($result);
}
```

I would then want to execute:

```
#TRUE allows this to show
if($result = True){
    echo "<p> No current work orders are open. Good Work !</p>\n";
    return;
}
```

If i change database in work_orders.is_open , the boolean is 0, meaning its "not open" .. the if statement for TRUE above, still shows...

I am sure that I'm missing something.

Comment: try `$result == True` (two `=` signs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I have solved my own question:

the if statement should just test for rows that were returned or not.

```
if($result->num_rows == 0)
```

this would allow it to show if there is nothing returned. If results are returned then it will continue moving forward.

Comment: You should use SELECT COUNT(*) instead of SELECT *